# How to access custom fields to a product with stripe and with those fields, add a stock limit to each field?

Tags: javascript, exception, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm making an ecommerce with nextjs and I'm using stripe for my checkout. recently, I discovered stripe has custom fields, that for instance you can add: small, medium and large options for the clothes size.

But here is the problem: with this implementation, the size options shows up in the checkout session, which makes the behavior very strange and counter-intuitive for the user, because he is choosing the size option on the checkout session and not in the product page. This is the first problem, the second problem is: how can I make an stock limit to each option, for instance, if I have 30 t-shirts on medium size, and 100 t-shirts with small size, I need to control this information on my app. Is possible to do this with stripe or am I limited by the tool?

This is how my stripe checkout session on code looks like right now:

```
const checkoutSession = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    success_url: successUrl,
    cancel_url: cancelUrl,
    invoice_creation: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    payment_method_types: ["card", "boleto"],
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ["BR"],
    },
    phone_number_collection: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    custom_fields: [
      {
        key: "size",
        label: {
          custom: "Size",
          type: "custom",
        },
        dropdown: {
          // Include up to 200 options as required
          options: [
            {
              label: "Small",
              value: "small",
            },
          ],
        },
        type: "dropdown",
      },
    ],
    mode: "payment",
    line_items: products.map(({ prod, quantity }) => ({
      price: prod.defaultPriceId,
      quantity: quantity,
    })),
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout's `custom_fields` [feature](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-fields) was designed so that you can configure Checkout to collect additional custom information you need. For example you might want to collect someone's Discord handle when they pay for your online chat bot.

What this means is that this was never designed as a way for you to "specialize" the Product/Price you're selling on Checkout this way. I don't think the approach you're taking would really work even if it appears to fit your needs.

What you need to do instead is have separate Product and Price objects that model the different versions of what you're selling such as a certain t-shirt in small, medium or large would be a different Product. Stripe doesn't really offer a way to model a "product catalog" with hierarchy between products today.

Similarly, Stripe doesn't have any "inventory" feature today that would fit your needs. The only solution here is really for you to track your overall inventory. You'd also track ongoing transactions where they might have the item in their "cart" but haven't paid yet.

There isn't really an alternative better than building most of this yourself today on Stripe.

Comment: i got what you said, i didnt metioned this in my question, but i imagined stripe would have some kind of tool that would help with that, because the products that are in the store, are created by the stripe, im thinking the only solution should be create a different a product by one api of my own and costumize as i see fit, and send those products to stripe

Comment: They do not have anything like what you are after today as far as I am aware. You really need to build most of this logic on your end or have separate Products for this with the right description and image(s) and such.